# object rotation around local axes

Tags: 3d, webgl, webgl2

I want to rotate an object around he's coordinates. 
For an example, I want to have three cubes in a row on the screen
let assume that I have a class shape that has a property transformMatrix.

```
export class Shape {
  constructor(vertices, indices, gl) {
  this.id = ++id
  this.gl = gl;
  this.vertices = vertices;
  this.indices = indices;
  this.color = [];
  this.generateColor();

  this.transformMatrix = mat4.create();
...
  this.baseTranslation = {}
...
}
```

By default, shape draws by vertices. This is a cube vertex.

```
-0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
 0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
-0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
 0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
-0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
-0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
 0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
```

and indices

```
   0, 1, 2,
   0, 2, 3,
   4, 5, 6,
   4, 6, 7,
   5, 0, 3,
   5, 3, 6,
   1, 4, 7,
   1, 7, 2,
   5, 4, 1,
   5, 1, 0,
   3, 2, 7,
   3, 7, 6,
```

Then for each shape during initialization I will translate it a bit and scale to see them on screen in a row.

```
// translation values for each shape
const baseTranslation = [
    [-1.5, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1.5, 0, 0],
]
// usage
// shapes.forEach((shape,i) => 
//   shape.setBaseTranslation(baseTranslation[i]))

setBaseTranslation(coordinates) {
  const BASE_SCALE = 0.33
  this.baseTranslation.x = coordinates[0]
  this.baseTranslation.y = coordinates[1]
  this.baseTranslation.z = coordinates[2]

  const {x,y,z} = this.baseTranslation
  const array = [x,y,z]

  mat4.scale(this.transformMatrix, this.transformMatrix, [BASE_SCALE, 
    BASE_SCALE, BASE_SCALE])
  mat4.translate(this.transformMatrix, this.transformMatrix, array)
}
```

And this what I get on a screen.
[image: screen]

I can choose which shape is active and transform it. 
On keydown event, I'm starting to transform active shape. 
If I want to have a transformation (rotation) around shape axes I need to translate it to (0,0) global coordinate, then rotate and then translate back. 
I want to use for all transformation just one matrix for a shape.
This is how looks my transformation func on keydown event.

```
// {Array} @actions
//   @name mat4 function
//   {GLFloat32Array|GLFloat} @value to transform

transform(actions) {
  const {x, y, z} = this.baseTranslation

  // translate back 
  mat4.translate(this.transformMatrix, this.transformMatrix, [x, y, z]);

  actions.forEach(action => {
    const key = action.name;
    const value = action.value;

    mat4[key](this.transformMatrix, this.transformMatrix, value);
  });

  // translate to center
  mat4.translate(
     this.transformMatrix, 
     this.transformMatrix, 
     [-(x), -(y), -(z)]);

}
```

When I rotate middle box, rotation works as expected.

[image]

But when I switch to first or last then rotation goes around another point.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't you want to translate negative before and positive after?

Comment: @gman but should be multiplying of matrixes in invert order? Anyway it change pivot and cube start rotates around another point but not  around itself

Comment: @Rabbid76 maybe u can help?

Comment: @gman Any suggestion for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677748/calculate-mat4-rotate-on-vertex-position